# how is the counter of the counter mode of AES incremented?

Tags: java, encryption, aes, counter

Hello and sorry in advance for my broken English.
I would like in a project to realize several different encryption from a character string.

So I turned to the counter mode of AES (which I have already used in python without any problem)

But when I use the program below twice on the same string the result is exactly the same.
I probably don't understand how AES works. But I wonder if the counter increments by itself or not.

I tried to use an Iv but must I increment it myself to have a different result?

Here's a sample code:

```
String key = "thisisa128bitkey";

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/PKCS5PADDING");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(gu.getGraine().getBytes());
System.out.println("first id : "+Base64.encodeToString(encrypted,Base64.DEFAULT));

byte[] encrypted2 = cipher.doFinal(gu.getGraine().getBytes());
System.out.println("second id: "+Base64.encodeToString(encrypted2,Base64.DEFAULT));
```

Here gu.getGraine() is a simple string.
For display the two values ​​are identical

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: I want different encryptions of the same plaintext to result in different ciphertexts. I guess I'm using bad techno. But on python after each encryption on a String a new encryption on this string give a different result with the counter mode. And I wanted to replicate the code from Python to java. This technique allows me to generate several ephemeral identifiers from the same string

Comment: I see. If you're not storing the IV, you cannot recreate the identifier from the string again. Then you must somehow store or transmit the ephemeral identifier to be useful. In that case you could just generate an identifier randomly without any encryption at all. If you don't ever need to decrypt it, then hashing or HMAC might also be a solution for you, but that is deterministic too.

Comment: I need to decipher it later so same question as below if I store 4 different Ivs can I reuse the Ivs on other Strings without encountering critical problems?

Answer (score 1):

The counter is incremented every time a new block (AES is a block cipher) needs to be encrypted. When you feed data into the `Cipher` object through `update` or `doFinal` then it decides internally whether the current block is full and the counter needs to be incremented for further blocks.

I assume that you want different encryptions of the same plaintext to result in different ciphertexts. When you initialize `Cipher`, you can either pass in your own IV (which defines the initial internal counter) or not specify the IV at all. When omitting the IV, it is internally randomly generated and accessible to you through `Cipher#getIV`.

Calling `Cipher#doFinal` resets all internal values to their initial positions after the encryption is finished. When you call it again with the same data on the same `Cipher` instance the previously generated IV will be used again from the beginning. If you want to have a fresh IV, you need to re-initialze the `Cipher` instance.

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/PKCS5PADDING");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec); // generates an IV

byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(gu.getGraine().getBytes());
System.out.println("first id : "+Base64.encodeToString(encrypted,Base64.DEFAULT));

cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec); // generates a different IV

byte[] encrypted2 = cipher.doFinal(gu.getGraine().getBytes());
System.out.println("second id: "+Base64.encodeToString(encrypted2,Base64.DEFAULT));
```

Keep in mind that you **need** the IV later for decryption. The IV is not supposed to be secret and needs only be unique for CTR mode and with the same key. The IV can be set to a static value when it is *guaranteed* that the key changes for each encryption.

Comment: Thanks for this answer and yes I want want different encryptions of the same plaintext to result in different ciphertexts.  so if I understood correctly for my problem I am obliged to generate a new IV each time have a different encrypted data?

Comment: Exactly, if you don't generate a fresh IV it is a catastrophic break in confidentiality of your ciphertexts because then you have a [many-time pad](https://www.thecrowned.org/the-one-time-pad-and-the-many-time-pad-vulnerability) on your hands.

Comment: So I should avoid using the same Iv and the same key for two different strings? So let's imagine I have to create 4 different encryption form from several String. can I create 4 Iv that I will reuse for all the chains?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by chain. If you reuse an IV then an attacker who gets access to the two ciphertexts (different plaintexts but same IV and same key) then they are able to see the XOR difference between the two plaintexts. If they know a part of one of the plaintexts then they know the same part of the other plaintext. If the plaintexts follow a certain pattern then they might even be able to deduce more of the plaintext simply by observing the XOR difference. This deduction gets easier the more often you reuse the IV.